# How to execute code that is in a string?

Tags: c#

Say I have something like this:

```
string singleStatement = "System.DateTime.Now";
```

Is there some way to take `singleStatement` and parse and run it at run time?

So that:

```
DateTime currentTime = singleStatement.SomeCoolMethodToRunTheText();
```

would assign the value of `DateTime.Now` to `currentTime`.

Comment: Can I query why you would want to?

Comment: http://scriptcs.net/ ? :)

Answer (score 4):

Read [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/267382-possible-execute-code-contained-string#post1071304) (quote follows).

That's possible : have a look to `System.CodeDom` and `System.CodeDom.Compiler`.

I have found an example I wrote few months ago :
assume `usingList` is an `arraylist` with all using statement (without using
keyword, `System.Xml` for example)
assume `importList` is an `arraylist` with all dll name that are necessary for
compilation (`system.dll` for example)
assume `source` is the source code you want to compile
assume `classname` is the name of the class you want to compile
assume `methodname` is the name of the method

**Have a look at the following code:**

```
//Create method
CodeMemberMethod pMethod = new CodeMemberMethod();
pMethod.Name = methodname;
pMethod.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
pMethod.Parameters.Add(new
CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(typeof(string[]),"boxes"));
pMethod.ReturnType=new CodeTypeReference(typeof(bool));
pMethod.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetExpression(@"
bool result = true;
try
{
    " + source + @"
}
catch
{
    result = false;
}
return result;
"));

//Crée la classe
CodeTypeDeclaration pClass = 
  new System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration(classname);
pClass.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
pClass.Members.Add(pMethod);
//Crée le namespace
CodeNamespace pNamespace = new CodeNamespace("myNameSpace");
pNamespace.Types.Add(pClass);
foreach(string sUsing in usingList)
  pNamespace.Imports.Add(new
    CodeNamespaceImport(sUsing));

//Create compile unit
CodeCompileUnit pUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
pUnit.Namespaces.Add(pNamespace);
//Make compilation parameters
CompilerParameters pParams = 
  new CompilerParameters((string[])importList.ToArray(typeof(string)));
pParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
//Compile
CompilerResults pResults =
  (new CSharpCodeProvider())
    .CreateCompiler().CompileAssemblyFromDom(pParams, pUnit);

if (pResults.Errors != null && pResults.Errors.Count&gt;0)
{
    foreach(CompilerError pError in pResults.Errors)
      MessageBox.Show(pError.ToString());
    result =
    pResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("myNameSp ace."+classname);
}
```

---

For example,

```
if 'usingList' equals
{
    "System.Text.RegularExpressions"
}
if 'importList' equals
{
    "System.dll"
}
if 'classname' equals "myClass"
if 'methodName' equals "myMethod"
if 'source' equals "
string pays=@"ES
FR
EN
"
Regex regex=new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]
{
    2
}
$");
result=regex.IsMatch(boxes[0]);
if (result)
{
    regex=new Regex(@"^"+boxes[0]+@".$",RegexOptions.Multiline);
    result=regex.Matches(pays).Count!=0;
}
```

Then the code that will be compiled will be the following:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myNameSpace
{
    public class myClass
    {
        public bool myMethod(string[] boxes)
        {
            bool result=true;
            try
            {
                string pays=@"ES
                FR
                EN
                "
                Regex regex=new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]
                {
                    2
                }
                $");
                result=regex.IsMatch(boxes[0]);
                if (result)
                {
                    regex=new Regex(@"^"+boxes[0]+@".$",RegexOptions.Multiline);
                    result=regex.Matches(pays).Count!=0;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                result=false;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible only by using compiler services and `Reflection.Emit()` which will compile and assembly and load into memory.

Have a look here.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/419/

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the code at run time using using a CSharpCodeProvider object. Whether you really want to do this or not is up for debate. :-)