# Generate C# assembly from source code text file

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I have a C# source code in the file (or in text string). How can I use reflection emit to generate and execute this code?

There are so many examples where people generate one class, then add a method etc, but I need top compile-on-the-fly huge piece of C# code, couple kilobytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800267/how-to-execute-code-that-is-in-a-string

Comment: Check out [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9019/Compiling-and-Executing-Code-at-Runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Reflection.Emit is for working with code at the IL level, it knows nothing about how to compile C# source code, so you can't use it for that.

What you can use for this instead is [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx), specifically [the `CSharpCodeProvider` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider) and its [`CompileAssemblyFromFile ()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromfile) or [`CompileAssemblyFromSource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.compileassemblyfromsource) methods.