# how to retrieve value and range of values from AND conditions

Tags: c#

If I write this piece of code in a textfield `if(value < 4)`, my program will generate the following table

```
value    Output
 3        True
 5        False
```

The table will dynamically change in size depending on the conditions.
The values 3 and 5 were randomly generated.

I'm stuck when it comes to more than one condition.

For example, when it comes to this `if (value > 4 && value <= 10)`.
Note: I have  functions for each of these conditions: `=, <, >, <=, >=, !=`

How do I get it to give me a true value that is in the range and a false value?

Comment: Show us the code of your functions please.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment ;)

Comment: So you're looking for the input ranges that result in either `true` or `false`? Which would be `true: range(-inf, 3), false: range(4, inf)` for the first example and `true: range(5, 10), false: range(-inf, 4), range(11, inf)` for the second?

Comment: You said that 3 and 5 were randomly generated, and were examples of values that both satisfied and did not satisfy a predicate with one condition.. OK, so why did you then not generate 3 and 5 randomly for your predicate that had two conditions? 3 and 5 also have the property that one does not satisfy the predicate and the other does. I can't figure out what you're actually asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know how you've implemented it so far I would recommend you to have a look at this [How to execute code that is in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800267/how-to-execute-code-that-is-in-a-string)

Then you would not have to worry about order of execution  &&, parentheses etc. Just have the string compile and the runtime will solve your problem just like you would have written it in an console app

But if it is a homework assignment I guess you would have trouble explaining this solution!