# Saving instructions for later evaluation, possible?

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, delayed-execution

I want to save "instructions" for how a value should be determined at a later time, instead of saving the actual value at the current time.
Is this even possible?

A simple C# example:

```
int[] myArray = new int[2];
Dictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
//dictionary type can be changed if required

myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;

myDictionary.Add("total", (myArray[0] + myArray[1]) ); // Don't evaluate the value now

myArray[0] = 3;
myArray[1] = 4;

Console.WriteLine("total 2 = " + myDictionary["total"]); // Evaluate the value now
//Desired output: 7 (3+4), actual output = 3 (1+2)
```

Comment: What a strange dictionary, is there something else apart from `total`?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800267/how-to-execute-code-that-is-in-a-string

Comment: * Tim, it's just an example, in this dictionary there is only "total", but in the real dictionary there will be more entries.

* Fernando, I will take a look at it.

Comment: * vc 74, I'm not sure how to read that, it looks like an anonymous function that returns summary?

Comment: A bunch of instructions that computes a result on demand is called a "method" in C#.  Put your code in a method. When you want it activated, **call the method**.

Comment: **For future readers**, this thread is quite similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233536/c-sharp-store-functions-in-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You could use [(expression bodied read-only) properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#expression-bodied-function-members):

```
public int[] MyArray { get; set; }

public string CurrentResult => $"total: {MyArray.Sum()} ({string.Join("+", MyArray)})";
```

You can use [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) if you need local variables:

```
string GetCurrentResult() => $"total: {MyArray.Sum()} ({string.Join("+", MyArray)})";

MyArray[0] = 1;
MyArray[1] = 2;
Console.WriteLine(GetCurrentResult()); // total: 3 (1+2)
MyArray[0] = 3;
MyArray[1] = 4;
Console.WriteLine(GetCurrentResult()); // total: 7 (3+4)
```

If you don't use C#7 you could use a `Func<string>` delegate:

```
Func<string> GetCurrentResult = () => $"total: {MyArray.Sum()} ({string.Join("+", MyArray)})";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It takes a `Func<T>` that doesn't evaluate until it is accessed via the `Value` property. Once it is evaluated, the result is stored for further access. So your code might look something like:

```
int[] myArray = new int[2];

var total = new Lazy<int>(() => myArray.Sum());
myArray[0] = 1;
myArray[1] = 2;
myArray[0] = 3;
myArray[1] = 4;

Console.WriteLine("total = " + total);
Console.WriteLine("total = " + total.Value);
Console.WriteLine("total = " + total);
```

The output of this code is:

```
total = Value is not created.
total = 7
total = 7
```

Note that, without calling `total.Value`, the result is not an `int` but rather a message telling us the expression hasn't been evaluated yet. Once `total.Value` has been called, subsequent accesses to `total` yield the value (due to implicit `ToString()` call in the `Console.WriteLine()`).

The benefit of using `Lazy<T>` is that the value is persisted, instead of being recalculated each time it is accessed. This makes it great for properties/fields in classes that may not be accessed each time the class is used but take a long time to generate a value.

## Edit: Based on Op's feedback `Lazy<T>` isn't exactly what they are looking for.

If you always want to evaluate the expression each time it is accessed, you want a method or `Func<T>`. So imagine you have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int[] Vals {get;set;}
}
```

If you want to define a custom way of getting the (for example) sum of `Vals`, you have a couple of simple options.

## A Class method

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int[] Vals {get;set;}
    public int SumOfVals()
    {
        return Vals.Sum();
    }
}
```

If you opt for the class method, you could (conceivably) make the class generic (`MyClass<T>`) and use a virtual/abstract method to implement the concrete `SumOfVals` method.

## A `Func<T>` implemented in the Class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int[] Vals {get;set;}
    public Func<int[], int> SumOfVals { get;set; }
}
```

Now you can set `SumOfVals` to some custom function each time the class is instantiated. If you don't set it to anything, you'll get a NullReferenceException if you try to do anything with it.

## A `Func<T>` implemented inline

```
var vals = new int[2];
var sumVals = new Func<int[], int>((arr) => arr.Sum());
Console.WriteLine(sumVals(vals));
```

This is probably the most flexible, but this can lead to some spaghetti code. I would recommend just creating either a method in the class that calls into `MyClass` or creating a method in `MyClass` to handle this logic.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it's only evaluated the first time, if I change the array and then run total.Value again, I still get the old value. It basically works as desired the first time, then it have the same problem as my first example code.

Comment: It would have been a perfect solution if Lazy<T> had some form of re-evaluation function, but I can't find any in the documentation.