# How to evaluate single string in IF c#

Tags: c#

is it possible to evaluate a single string in c#. The string itself will only be determined during run-time and therefore cannot be set before hand. please see example:

```
var a = "a == b";

if(a){
 //do something
}
```

EDITED:

This is a actual example of what i would like computed:

```
var evaluationToBeDone = "MUST_CE_I = \"MUST_CE_I\"";

if(evaluationToBeDone){
   // i will do something if the above is true
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate C# code dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-evaluate-c-sharp-code-dynamically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute code that is in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800267/how-to-execute-code-that-is-in-a-string)

Comment: Instead of telling us what you're doing, explain what you are trying to achieve because [what you are doing makes no sense at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Comment: all i want to do is evaluate a string such as "a == a" inside a IF statement. the string itself will be determined during runtime and set before the IF statement. Only inbuilt methods can be used ( such as "System.Expressions" etc) does this explain it?

Comment: It sounds like you might have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Instead of asking us about what you _think_ the solution is, describe your actual problem because its likely easily solvable another way.

Comment: essentially i have a single string that needs to be evaluated by the contents of it. i can use expression parsing, lambda expression and any other tool i can find aslong as i can get a boolean answer of true or false based on the strings contents

Comment: @WadeMartin ok, I see the update.  One more thing I want to ask.  What is controlling this input?  _Where_ are you getting this type of input from?  Is this something you can control?

Comment: @maccettura Yes its something i control however it is string that is built during runtime for the evaluation to occur and thats why i am not able to use the conventional IF statement [ such as if(evaluationToBeDone == "something") ]

Comment: @WadeMartin What does "built during runtime" mean.  Please describe what this input represents and how it ultimately gets into this string.  I really, truly believe you have an XY Problem here.

Comment: Built during runtime means i have this initially: "<#Case.Customer#> = 'MUST_CE_I' " after which "<#Case.Customer#>" is something that is set during runtime from a collection(makes use of a expression parsing algorythm). the end result after expression parsing results in: "MUST_CE_I = \"MUST_CE_I\"".

Comment: This new string now needs to be computed in order to achieve either a true or false. The reason i do not use a substring or a split to do so in a IF statment is because if in the future i decide to use integers in my evaluation such as: "<#Case.Customer#>  > 2 " then i do not want to recreate my IF statment as i might still have cases where i use to = operand. I hope i explained this well enough

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do, but the approach doesn't make sense. When you make a variable into an object, the program only reads it as letters, not any logic inside of the object. Try doing this:

```
var a = "MUST_CE_I"
var b = "\"MUST_CE_I\""

if (a == b)
{
   do stuff
}
```

I assume you want your second string to have the " " quotes, so this should give you what you need. Even though the if statement will always return false since the two variables are not equal.